# MPI RMA get safer than MPI RMA put?

Tags: memory, mpi

I am reading through *Using Advanced MPI* by Gropp et al., currently looking at RMA operations.  Discussing `MPI_Win_fence` calls, they say

> A good rule for using `MPI_Win_fence` is to ensure that between any pair
> of successive `MPI_Win_fence` calls, there may be either local stores
> ... to the local memory window *or* RMA put or accumulate operations (or
> neither), *but* not *both* local stores and RMA put or accumulate
> operations.

(italics mine).

I get this ... as far as it goes.  But I am surprised they make no mention of RMA get operations here.  So I am wondering, is this an oversight?  Or are gets somehow safer than put operations?  I can see that if you are doing a get into local memory that is not part of the local RMA window, that might free you of issues that you would have with a put into a window.  But it's completely possible to do a get into memory that happens to be part of a local window, so you can't rely on gets always going into non-window memory.  So why no mention of gets here?

Answer (score 0):

The passage you quote is about put and store and how they can be mixed or not. You should never mix put/store with get/load, so get is not mentioned in that passage.

However, he  mentions `MPI_Get` in the next sentence: "if there are no put operations there may be get or load operations" (paraphrase).